# how to set selected value in <%= f.select_tag %> dropdown list, how?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a long list dropdown menu including all currencies, i want the last selected value to be the default selected value in the list.
i am using Rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0

i am not using a model, i am just using a controller. i have put the dropdown list options inside a helper.

### form.html.erb

```
<div class="calculator">

    <%= form_for :convertor, :url => {:controller => "converter", :action => "show" } do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :from_currency %>
        <%= f.select :from_currency, options_for_select(currencies, :selected => params[:from_currency]) %>
        <%= f.text_field :amount, :placeholder => "Amount", id: "textfield" %>
        <%= @amount %>
        <br>

        <%= f.label :to_currency %>
        <%= f.select :to_currency, options_for_select(currencies, :selected => params[:to_currency].to_i ) %>
        <%= @result %>
        <br>

        <%= f.submit "Calculate", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", id: "submitButton" %> 
    <% end %>

</div>
```

---

the list options are loaded from a helper *<%= f.select :to_currency, options_for_select(currencies, :selected => params[:to_currency].to_i ) %>* with name currencies

### the dropdown list, in a helper

```
def currencies
    [
        ['United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)', 'AED'],
        ['Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)', 'ANG'],
        ['Argentine Peso (ARS)', 'ARS'],
        ['Australian Dollar (A$)', 'AUD'],
        ['Bangladeshi Taka (BDT)', 'BDT'],
        ['Bulgarian Lev (BGN)', 'BGN'],
        ['Bahraini Dinar (BHD)', 'BHD'],
    ]
end
```

---

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You can check out this link http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select]

Comment: and i think the one of the value is nil.

Comment: @Amit, i have read that one of the value maybe nil but i don't understand because in my controller i am using  params[:convertor][:from_currency] and params[:convertor][:to_currency] and they are  working fine

Comment: Put raise currencies.inspect in view before form and check the value.

Comment: check my edited answer and run the code if it works then surely there is an problem with ur params[:convertor][:to_currency]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can help

```
<%= f.label :from_currency %>
            <% if @from_cur.present? %>
                <%= f.select :from_currency, options_for_select(currencies,  @from_cur)  %>
            <% else %>
                <%= f.select :from_currency, options_for_select(currencies), :required => true %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.text_field :amount, :placeholder => "Amount", :required => true, id: "textfield"  %>
            <br>

            <%= f.label :to_currency %>
            <% if @from_cur.present? %>
                <%= f.select :to_currency, options_for_select(currencies,  @to_cur), :required => true %>
            <% else %>
                <%= f.select :to_currency, options_for_select(currencies), :required => true %>
            <% end %>
```

i appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. [`options_for_select` takes two arguments](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select): the list of options and the value that you want selected.
2. You're passing through the value as a hash: `:selected => params...`
3. The parameter name is wrong.

In your controller, you're saying that the parameter is called this:

```
params[:convertor][:from_currency]
```

But in your view, you have `params[:from_currency]`.

Therefore, the solution to this is to do this:

```
<%= f.select :from_currency, options_for_select(currencies, params[:convertor][:from_currency]) %>
```

Comment: hello Ryan, i am getting an error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass .(for that line)

Comment: Ah, that would be because params[:convertor] is not set. You need to check for that before you use it there.

Comment: thanks ryan, u were right. it was in my initial form so the values were not set. i solved the question.

Comment: @ben: The polite thing to do now would be to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you answer your question.

Comment: :-), i actually did. but i am new so my reputation can't allow. i did put the answer their in-case anybody else has the same question. upvote my question (and answer too)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

in application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def opts_for_select_cur
    opts_for_select = [
      ['United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)', 'AED'],
      ['Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)', 'ANG'],
      ['Argentine Peso (ARS)', 'ARS'],
      ['Australian Dollar (A$)', 'AUD'],
      ['Bangladeshi Taka (BDT)', 'BDT'],
      ['Bulgarian Lev (BGN)', 'BGN'],
      ['Bahraini Dinar (BHD)', 'BHD'],
    ]

    return opts_for_select
  end
end
```

and in view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#st').change(function(){
  var inputText = $('#st :selected').val();
  $("#hidden_one").val(inputText);

  $("a").attr("href", "?value="+inputText );

 });
 $('#aa').click(function(){
  var inputText = $('#st :selected').val();
  $("a").attr("href", "?value="+inputText );
});
```

});

```
<%= f.select :text, options_for_select(opts_for_select_cur, params[:value]), {}, { id: "st" } %>
<br>
<%= link_to "refresh",nil, id: "aa" %>
```

**the result is a select box with selected value.**

Comment: i have tried it but still not working, getting the same error

Comment: yes that will work, but i wanted everytime i select a value in the dropdown menu the default selected value to be changed to that value. such that the next time i load the page, the selected value will be "the last clicked value". do you have another way to do that?

Comment: I think on page refresh this is not possible but if you are using link or button to reload the page then it is possible.

Comment: you are right, that would work but i found another way. thanks i appreciate the help